# Identifiability of Gaussian process parameters

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, gaussian-process, identifiability

The Gaussian process model (GP) is written as 
$$y(x)=h(x)^{t}\boldsymbol\beta + f(x)+\epsilon(x)\qquad[1]$$
where $h(x)^{t}$ is a regression function such as $\left [1,x,x^{2} \right ]$ ;  $\boldsymbol\beta$ is the set of regression coefficients and $\epsilon(x)$ is normal with zero mean and $\sigma^{2}$ variance and $f_{i}(x)$ is a Gaussian process with a covariance matrix $K_{\theta}$. Where $\theta$ represents the covariance hyperparameters.

The Gaussian process (GP) Likelihood is known to be non-convex for most well known covariance functions (exponentail, Maternal, Gaussian) and different local maxima correspond to different interpretations of the data (as is mentioned in Rasmussen's famous GP [Book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf)).

I am wondering whether the parameters of the GP (ex:  $\theta, \boldsymbol\beta $) are uniquely identifiable ?

Also, when do GP parameters lack indentifiability. I would greatly appreciate any references on the identifiability of GP parameter estimates.

Comment: For $\beta$, wouldn't be the same as for linear regression? Like, if $h(x)^T=[x, x]$ then it wouldn't be identifiable because $\beta$ and $\beta'$ give the same model as long as the sum of the components of $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are equal? But if the components are linearly independent, then it would be identifiable

Comment: In linear regression noise is assumed $iid$ normal. In GP, we model residuals as a correlated process through the covariance matrix $K$. In the GP we estimate both $\theta$ and $\beta$ together.

Comment: Yeah I was just pointing out that the identifiability of $\beta$ depends on $h$

Comment: yes I do agree. Lets say I assume here that such case is not included in the set of regression basis functions.

Comment: My take is that the only obstacle to identifiability is between $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$. You can probably drop the $\epsilon(x)$ term and let the gaussian process $f$ account for all of the variation.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\sigma$ is known, or not?

Comment: Sigma is unknown

Comment: Yes, for generic mean functions and covariance functions Gaussian Process Regression can easily be unidentifiable. This doesn't affect predictions, but it does make the mean function uninterpretable: see for example [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00203&ved=0ahUKEwjF9e6x6KHUAhVEvRQKHfqMByIQFggyMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHaO2Luxz1cyUcEuar29ixP7-hZ3Q&sig2=plqo66VQlHb-v4IZRX16TA). Paul Arendt has studied the issue extensively in the context of model calibration.